# Promise.all rollback successful promises' actions on failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, async-await

I am executing multiple promises with the following snippet:

```
await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

What I would like to achieve is to rollback the effects of the successful promises on the case of a failure from `Promise.all()`. 
In more specific terms, this means that the above will do some file encryptions, but if one fails, I would like to delete the other two (or one) files that were encrypted successfully so as to have consistent and clean file groups.

From what I've read this means that I would need two steps:
1. Catching the errors for each promise so that `Promise.all()` won't throw an error.
2. The puzzling part: Having another `Promise.all()` sort of:

```
await Promise.all([rollbackPromise1, rollbackPromise2, rollbackPromise3]);
```

This one seems to be the tricky part: Should I execute all the rollbacks independent of the promise that failed? This means that I should do another catch for every error such that the `Promise.all()` waits for every rollback to finish.

Is this the best way to do this, I find it pretty inefficient and ugly in terms of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function waits for all promises until 1 fails. Then it calls *all* rollback functions:

```
/**
 * Given an array of tuples with a promise and a rollback function that returns
 * a function, `allOrNothing` awaits promises and if any of them fail, calls
 * all rollback functions achieving an "all or nothing" effect.
 */
export async function allOrNothing(
  promisesWithRollbacks: [Promise<unknown>, () => Promise<unknown>][]
): Promise<unknown[]> {
  const promises: Promise<unknown>[] = [];
  const rollbacks: (() => Promise<unknown>)[] = [];
  for (const [promise, rollback] of promisesWithRollbacks) {
    promises.push(promise);
    rollbacks.push(rollback);
  }
  try {
    return Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // in case any rollback functions fail, we want others to have time to complete
    return Promise.allSettled(rollbacks);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, at the time I think I used the Top Voted answer since I fulfilled my need, but this is indeed an all rollback in case of one failure.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own function implementing the asynchronous call of the functions and performing a rollback if required.

```js
// Function that'll perform a promise.all and rollback if required
async function allWithRollback(promises) {
  // using the map we are going to wrap the promise inside of a new one
  return Promise.all(promises.map(([
    func,
    rollbackFunc,
  ], xi) => ((async() => {
    try {
      await func;

      console.log('One Function succeed', xi);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('One Function failed, require rollback', xi);

      await rollbackFunc();
    }
  })())));
}

// Call the custom Promise.all
allWithRollback([
  [
    // First param is the promise
    okPromise(),

    // Second param is the rollback function to execute
    () => {},
  ],
  [okPromise(), () => {}],
  [errPromise(), rollback1],
  [errPromise(), rollback2],
  [okPromise(), () => {}],
]);

// ---------

async function okPromise() {
  return true;
}

async function errPromise() {
  throw new Error('no one read this');
}

async function rollback1() {
  console.log('Performed the rollback1');
}

async function rollback2() {
  console.log('Performed the rollback2');
}
```

Comment: I assume there will be `rollback`-s for the `okPromise()`-s too, if I understand it correctly. Makes sense.

Is this kind of logic sensible(the one I've used with rollbacks) in dealing with these kinds of problems? Because the rollback functions could have their own failures, so there is no way to actually ensure the execution. Does it make sense to do this thing, or should it be left to be done manually, and just noticed as an error log. Because later on I have a lot more executions that could fail, and having rollbacks to include to all the previous rollbacks seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Yes the `okPromise()` have theirs rollback as well.

Adding an automatic rollback can be appropriate depending on the issue. Some issue are "expected" and you have to deal with them. When it's unexpected, a log and a manual treatment seems appropriate.

It's all about the context. Does errors are often ? How important the error can led to? Does my system availability must be 99.99% ? Does my database will corrupted in case of no rollback?

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. This solution or rolls back the failed promises. It doesn't "rollback the effects of the successful promises".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a naive solution as follows:

```js
const errorHandlers = []
function enc1 () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('str')
    }, 1000)
    errorHandlers.push(() => {
      console.log('handler 1')
    })
  })
}
function enc2 () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('str')
    }, 2000)
    errorHandlers.push(() => {
      console.log('handler 2')
    })
  })
}
function enc3 () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject('str')
    }, 3000)
    errorHandlers.push(() => {
      console.log('handler 3')
    })
  })
}

Promise.all([enc1(), enc2(), enc3()]).then(() => {
  console.log('all resovled')
}).catch((e) => {
  errorHandlers.forEach(handler => handler(e))
})
```

It'd give you option to handle the 'global' error in each promise. Before creating promise all, you can reset the errorHandlers to prevent multiple errorHandler execution

Comment: I think this one, I am not mistaken, doesn't wait for the execution of the other promises as soon as one fails. This will mean that the errorHandlers may start executing in an unstable state, before the appropriate Promise has finished execution, failing or not.

Comment: "If I am not mistaken"